# NSInternalInconsistencyException with Parse

Tags: ios, debugging, exception, parse-platform

I have an application setup using Parse. Recently, I started getting the following error when my app starts up.

```
[Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child."
```

The app doesn't crash, as the exception is caught. However, I am unable to discern the cause of the exception. Below is the stack trace that is printed to the console:

```
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185f802f4 <redacted> + 160
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000197c4c0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185f80218 <redacted> + 0
    3   STSI                                0x0000000100305e4c -[PFPointerObjectEncoder encodeParseObject:] + 116
    4   STSI                                0x000000010030528c -[PFEncoder encodeObject:] + 148
    5   STSI                                0x00000001002d0254 __129+[PFRESTQueryCommand findCommandParametersWithOrder:conditions:selectedKeys:includedKeys:limit:skip:extraOptions:tracingEnabled:]_block_invoke97 + 1752
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185ed47a4 <redacted> + 88
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185ec1cec <redacted> + 240
    8   STSI                                0x00000001002cfa9c +[PFRESTQueryCommand findCommandParametersWithOrder:conditions:selectedKeys:includedKeys:limit:skip:extraOptions:tracingEnabled:] + 936
    9   STSI                                0x00000001002cf69c +[PFRESTQueryCommand findCommandParametersForQueryState:] + 348
    10  STSI                                0x00000001002cf074 +[PFRESTQueryCommand findCommandForQueryState:withSessionToken:] + 84
    11  STSI                                0x00000001002dccdc __78-[PFQueryController findObjectsAsyncForQueryState:withCancellationToken:user:]_block_invoke + 116
    12  STSI                                0x000000010034f9ec __55-[BFTask continueWithExecutor:block:cancellationToken:]_block_invoke_2 + 96
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c38fd4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c38f94 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c46b54 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2180
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100c48248 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001984a922c _pthread_wqthread + 816
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001984a8ef0 start_wqthread + 4
).
```

I'm quite clueless as to what this stack trace is implying. Additionally, in the debugger, I can see many stacks of BFTasks being allocated.

What is the reason behind the exception being raised?

Comment: What code did you change? Did you call save eventually on some objects? Local data store enabled?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause could be, as the issue cropped up after a big merge of branches. And yes to both the second and third questions.

Comment: It looks like save eventually is trying to save something which has a relationship to something else which isn't yet saved. Not really sure how to prove it or work around it...